# What does this error mean? "DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated" and how can I replicate it in nodejs12

Tags: node.js, deprecation-warning

I am occasionally getting the above error logged in AWS lambda. Just curious about it and want to  know how can I replicate it locally in nodejs12.

Comment: The line right after the warning, contains the answer: "Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created" (so basically you have to run the same function locally (installing the same dependencies as were bundled into the Lambda, of course!) adding the above flag)

Comment: Better upgrade your AWS lambda version. This warning mostly comes from your old version package which is using private property `._headers`. My case is that I'm using Express under v15. Express document v15 said that they no longer use private method `res._headers`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that one of your packages or yourself are using a deprecated feature as of that version of node.

You would need to figure out which module it is and see if there is a fix for the issue.

The packages themselves can fix the issue by changing anywhere they use `._headers` to `.getHeaders`

That said, this is only a warning, this wont currently break anything but it's always better to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Still I wanna know more about it. Like how can I use ._header ? and what is it used for ?

Comment: It's from the `http` module, so anywhere that uses http with the `_headers` property. I've personally never used it but I imagine it would allow you access to the request and response headers, if you take a look at the deprecation changelog you can see it was never an officially documented part of the API.

https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0066_outgoingmessage_prototype_headers_outgoingmessage_prototype_headernames

Comment: This helps. Thanks :)